# How can I use logging in terraform for an aws comprehend text classification model?

Tags: logging, terraform, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-comprehend

I'm creating an aws comprehend document classifier in my [terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/comprehend_document_classifier#output_data_config-configuration-block).  It looks like this:

```
resource "aws_comprehend_document_classifier" "doc-classifier" {

  data_access_role_arn = aws_iam_role.me.arn
  language_code = "en"

  input_data_config {
    s3_uri = "s3://somebucket/somedata.csv"
  }

  output_data_config {
    s3_uri = "s3://somebucket/output"
  }
}
```

It's been about a half hour of training on a simple fake dataset involving 2 classes.

`aws_comprehend_document_classifier.classifier: Still creating... [28m51s elapsed]`

In the console I see it is training.

Is there any way I can look at logs? How can I use logging in terraform for an aws comprehend text classification model?